# Retrieving records from other table column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a view where there are multiple column. I need to retrieve some data from an external table.
[image]
[image]

```
cte4 as (
SELECT *,
case 
    when roadName=roadNameUserData then sec1
else 'x' 
end as roadCrossSection1

FROM dbo.roadSectionAndPavementUserData,cte3
    )

--"roadName" is from cte computed column view
--"roadNameUserData" is from other table("dbo.roadSectionAndPavementUserData") where records are to be extracted
--sec1 is the column in table "dbo.roadSectionAndPavementUserData" where the results coming from 



-----final view
SELECT roadName,
sum(roadLength) as sumRoadLength,roadCrossSection1


FROM cte4 
group by roadName
order by roadName
```

When i execute the query, it came with the following error

> "Column 'cte4.roadCrossSection1' is invalid in the select list because
>   it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause."

[image]

This is the result after adding additional groupby statement. The correct records are the lesser values of sumRoadLength.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by `roadCrossSection1` as well

```
SELECT roadName, roadCrossSection1,
               sum(roadLength) as sumRoadLength
FROM cte4 
group by roadName, roadCrossSection1
order by roadName, roadCrossSection1
```

**Updated**

```
SELECT roadName, sum(roadLength) as sumRoadLength
FROM cte4 
group by roadName 
order by roadName
```

Comment: i tried your proposed solution it worked but it creates duplicate records. Originally i have 442 rows, but after applying additional groupby it became 884 where the other records are null. The second records came out the right result.

Comment: Please capture an image result then gives me it. Probably, the value `roadCrossSection1` and `roadName` are different. Future more, the `cte4` is joining without condition `FROM dbo.roadSectionAndPavementUserData,cte3`

Comment: what does `cte3` table look like?

Comment: I posted in my original question the image of recent result. I observed that the correct result should be the lesser values from roadName records and those values that are not nulls.

Comment: You need to remove `roadCrossSection1`.

Comment: I remove as you instructed by it doesnt change a thing. I has still duplicate records from nowhere.

Comment: remove in `group by` clause as well. It much looks like `group by roadName`

Comment: I've just updated my answer, please take a look at @Vincent

Answer (score 1):

From your comment:

> I observed that the correct result should be the lesser values from
>   roadName records and those values that are not nulls

I think that you need conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT roadName,
  sum(case when roadCrossSection1 is not null then roadLength end) as sumRoadLength,
  max(roadCrossSection1) roadCrossSection1
FROM cte4 
group by roadName
order by roadName
```

Answer (score 0):

Error says if you want roadCrossSection1 in select clause either you have to apply any aggregate function e.g MIN, Max, Sum, Avg on roadCrossSection1 or you have to put it in group by clause because roadCrossSection1 might have multiple values for same road name but at same time you are evaluating only one value for roadLength by calling aggregate function on roadLength